# Loading NPAPI plugin content on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, firefox, npapi

I would like to get a screenshot of what is being displayed in a NPAPI plugin content and put that image in a HTML5 Canvas on Firefox.
Is it possible?
If it is, could someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you can control the NPAPI plugin or not.  If you can't then it is basically not possible.

When I say "basically not" I mean that there might be a platform-specific hackish way of doing it, but nothing that would be supported by the browsers, etc.